# Explode string by one or more spaces or tabs

Tags: php, regex, explode

How can I explode a string by one or more spaces or tabs?

Example:

```
A      B      C      D
```

I want to make this an array.

Comment: zero or more spaces implies that either each element will have at most one character, or that you'll have infinitely many empty elements. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that should probably be "one or more spaces".

Answer (score 380, accepted):

```
$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
```

Comment: Instead of removing the last part which may be empty, one can use:
```$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);```

Answer (score 65):

To separate by tabs:

```
$comp = preg_split("/\t+/", $var);
```

To separate by spaces/tabs/newlines:

```
$comp = preg_split('/\s+/', $var);
```

To seperate by spaces alone:

`$comp = preg_split('/ +/', $var);`

Comment: To add to this `preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $var);` which requires atleast two spaces,

Comment: There is no benefit to writing `\t` inside of a character class.

Answer (score 26):

This works:

```
$string = 'A   B C          D';
$arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $string);
```

Comment: There is no benefit to writing `\s` inside of a character class.

Comment: @mickmackusa Could you clarify? This is pretty similar to the first example in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: @Hash the documentation's example is splitting on whitespaces AND commas.  When you have multiple items to list (`[\s,]`), then creating a "character class" is appropriate.  When you are only splitting on `\s` (whitespaces), then use the current syntax in this answer (edited by Dharman after I commented).

Answer (score 19):

The author asked for explode, to you can use explode like this

`$resultArray = explode("\t", $inputString);`

Note: you must used double quote, not single.

Comment: Worked for me and is a tad simpler than using the dark power of regular expressions.

Comment: But he asked for "spaces or tabs" and this only explodes for tabs.

Comment: I came here looking for exploding spaces too. I feel sad deep inside about this.

Comment: I am always sad to see provably incorrect answers upvoted to a point where they cannot be deleted by the community.

Comment: Please update to include spaces so that it answers the question.

Answer (score 10):

I think you want [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$input = "A  B C   D";
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $input);
var_dump($words);
```

Answer (score 4):

instead of using explode, try preg_split: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: This is not a generous post.  2009 was a sad era in terms of contribution quality for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

In order to account for **full width space** such as

```
full　width
```

you can extend Bens answer to this:

```
$searchValues = preg_split("@[\s+　]@u", $searchString);
```

Sources:

- [strip out multi-byte white space from a string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946518)
- [What are all the Japanese whitespace characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300980)

(I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so I'm wrote this as an answer.)

Comment: This answer should not be used.  The character class contains: 1. Whitespaces 2. Plus symbols and 3. literal spaces.  There is a fundamental lack of understanding in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$string = "\tA\t B \tC \t D ";` (a mix of tabs and spaces including leading tab and trailing space)

Obviously splitting on just spaces or just tabs will not work. **Don't use these**:

```
preg_split('~ +~', $string) // one or more literal spaces, allow empty elements
preg_split('~ +~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) // one or more literal spaces, deny empty elements

preg_split('~\t+~', $string) // one or more tabs, allow empty elements
preg_split('~\t+~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) // one or more tabs, deny empty elements
```

**Use these**:

```
preg_split('~\s+~', $string) // one or more whitespace character, allow empty elements
preg_split('~\s+~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), // one or more whitespace character, deny empty elements

preg_split('~[\t ]+~', $string) // one or more tabs or spaces, allow empty elements
preg_split('~[\t ]+~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)  // one or more tabs or spaces, deny empty elements

preg_split('~\h+~', $string) // one or more horizontal whitespaces, allow empty elements
preg_split('~\h+~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) // one or more horizontal whitespaces, deny empty elements
```

A [demonstration of all techniques below can be found here](https://3v4l.org/WSPDS).

Reference [Horizontal Whitespace](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#:%7E:text=%5Ch,%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5D)

Comment: This is the first answer that shows the concept of horizontal whitespaces. This is the most correct answer now, as the question asked only about tabs and spaces.