# What are all the Japanese whitespace characters?

Tags: text, unicode, whitespace, tokenize, cjk

I need to split a string and extract words separated by whitespace characters.The source may be in English or Japanese. English whitespace characters include tab and space, and Japanese text uses these too. (IIRC, all widely-used Japanese character sets are supersets of US-ASCII.)

So the set of characters I need to use to split my string includes normal ASCII space and tab.

But, in Japanese, there is another space character, commonly called a 'full-width space'. According to my Mac's Character Viewer utility, this is U+3000 "IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE". This is (usually) what results when a user presses the space bar while typing in Japanese input mode.

Are there any other characters that I need to consider?

I am processing textual data submitted by users who have been told to "separate entries with spaces".  However, the users are using a wide variety of computer and mobile phone operating systems to submit these texts. We've already seen that users may not be aware of whether they are in Japanese or English input mode when entering this data.

Furthermore, the behavior of the space key differs across platforms and applications even in Japanese mode (e.g., Windows 7 will insert an ideographic space but iOS will insert an ASCII space).

So what I want is basically "the set of all characters that visually look like a space and might be generated when the user presses the space key, or the tab key since many users do not know the difference between a space and a tab, in Japanese and/or English".

Is there any authoritative answer to such a question?

Comment: Shouldn't any programming language with proper Unicode support just let you split a string (using a regex) on whitespace? For example - `/\s/` matches whitespace characters in JavaScript (equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029]`).

Comment: Matt: The regex you quoted is already missing `\u3000` and the OP is wondering what else might be missing. The Unicode separator space list has 18 entries: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm

Comment: Matt: Yeah, I wish, but the notion that JavaScript (and surprisingly, even Ruby) has about what constitutes generic 'whitespace' does not include Japanese whitespace character(s?). Gabe: thank you for that link, poking around manually in my Unicode viewer I had stumbled accross EM SPACE, FIGURE SPACE and friends, but had not encountered OGHAM SPACE MARK or MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR...

Comment: Is this full width space character used for tokenizing Japanese text? If not then how in the world do you tokenize Japanese text?

Comment: FWIW, I have seen `\uFFE3` (overline) used as a full-width space as well (in the wild, on the Japanese web).

Comment: @taylor Japanese text almost never has whitespace (other than newlines). Tokenization and parsing is done using machine learning techniques like conditional random fields (CRF), trained on data that's been annotated with part-of-speech information.

Comment: @taylor, tokenizing Japanese text is hard. Yes they do have a period (full stop) type punctuation but it's more used to complete several sentences that formulate an idea (think paragraph). AFAIK, words are typically tokenized using a Trie data structure, or something similar but you have to take into consideration the context of the sentence to properly discern the actual word being tokenized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the ASCII tab, space and non-breaking space (U+00A0), and the full-width space, which you've correctly identified as U+3000.  You might possibly want newlines and vertical space characters.  If your input is in unicode (not Shift-JIS, etc.) then that's all you'll need.  There are other (control) characters such as \0 NULL which are sometimes used as information delimiters, but they won't be rendered as a space in East Asian text - i.e., they won't appear as white-space.

edit:  Matt Ball has a good point in his comment, but, as his example illustrates, many regex implementations don't deal well with full-width East Asian punctuation.  In this connection, it's worth mentioning that Python's `string.whitespace` won't cut the mustard either.

Comment: I really want to believe you, because that means I am done! :) But, how do you know?

Comment: I work with East Asian text of a variety of provenances on a daily basis.  what environment/programming language are you in?  perhaps I can give some more specific advice.  would a regex which works with everything in Gabe's link suffice?

Comment: You are right; while I ended up writing a method that dealt with all the weird spaces in Matt's link, I also manually tested submitting from 24 different platform/application combinations. Tab, space, U+00A0 and U+3000 were all that came up in the real world. So I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just found your posting. This is a great explantion about normalizing Unicode characters.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

I found that many programming languages, like Python, have modules that can implement these normalization rules the Unicode standards. For my purposes, I found the following python code works very well. It converts all unicode variants of whitespace to the ascii range. After the normalization, a regex command can convert all white space to ascii \x32:

```
import unicodedata
# import re

ucode = u'大変、 よろしくお願い申し上げます。'

normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', ucode)

# old code
# utf8text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', normalized).encode('utf-8')

# new code
utf8text = ' '.join(normalized.encode('utf-8').split())
```

Since the first writing, I learned Python's regex (re) module improperly itentifies these whitespace characters and can cause a crash if encountered. It turns out a faster, more reliable method to uses the .split() function.