# strip out multi-byte white space from a string PHP

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-replace, multibyte

I am trying to use a preg_replace to eliminate the Japanese full-width white space "　" from a string input but I end up with a corrupted multi-byte string.

I would prefer to preg_replace instead of str_replace. 
Here is a sample code:

```
$keywords = '　ラメ単色';
$keywords = str_replace(array(' ', '　'), ' ', urldecode($keywords)); // outputs :'ラメ単色'

$keywords = preg_replace("@[ 　]@", ' ',urldecode($keywords)); // outputs :'�� ��単色'
```

Anyone has any idea as to why this is so and how to remedy this situation?

Comment: Is `$keywords` the same as `'　ラメ単色'`?

Comment: yea, copied and edited in a haste

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the `u` flag to your regex. This makes the RegEx engine treat the input string as UTF-8.

```
$keywords = preg_replace("@[ 　]@u", ' ',urldecode($keywords));
// outputs :'ラメ単色'
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0kmBb4).

The reason it mangles the string is because to the RegEx engine, your replacement characters, `20` (space) or `e3 80 80` (IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE) are not treated as two characters, but separate bytes `20`, `e3` and `80`.

When you look at the byte sequence of your string to scan, we get `e3 80 80 e3 83 a9 e3 83 a1 e5 8d 98 e8 89 b2`. We know the first character is a IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE, but because PHP is treating it as a sequence of bytes, it does a replacement individually of the first four bytes, because they match individual bytes that the regex engine is scanning.

As for the mangling which results in the � (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER), we can see this happens because the byte `e3` is present further along in the string. The `e3` byte is the start byte of a three byte long Japanese character, such as `e3 83 a9` (KATAKANA LETTER RA). When that leading `e3` is replaced with a `20` (space), it no longer becomes a valid UTF-8 sequence.

When you enable the `u` flag, the RegEx engine treats the string as UTF-8, and won't treat your characters in your character class on a per-byte basis.

Comment: I am going accept yours as the answer since it makes use of my preferred preg_replace. The mb_ereg_replace also does the job though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid additional problems, also consider setting the internal encoding explicitly to your mb_* functions solution:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Always good to dig into the documentation. I found out that preg_* related function are not optimized for mulitbyte charaacter. Instead mb_ereg_* and mb_* functions are supposed to be used. I solved this little issue by refactoring the code to something like:

```
$keywords = '　ラメ単色';
$pattern = " "/*ascii whitespace*/ . "　"/*multi-byte whitespace*/;
$keywords = trim(
    mb_ereg_replace("[{$pattern}]+", ' ',urldecode($keywords))); // outputs:'ラメ単色'
```

Thanks all the same!

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$keywords = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',urldecode($keywords));
```

Comment: That won't match all the characters the OP wants to remove.