# explode() a string. Take off white space

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I need to explode $k like this

```
$kExploded = explode(" ", $k);
```

Now if it ca be useful I also add that

```
var_dump($k)= string(20) "2013-01-01 12:00:00 " string(20) "2013-01-02 12:00:00 " 
               string(20) "2013-01-03 12:00:00 "
```

How to explode $K?

if I echo out $k returns this

```
2013-01-01 12:00:00 2013-01-02 12:00:00 2013-01-03 12:00:00
```

**I just would like to get this:**

```
2013-01-0112:00:002013-01-0212:00:002013-01-0312:00:00//take off all white space
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand your problem. Can you make a more clear description of your problem?

Comment: This is a better solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792950/explode-string-by-one-or-more-spaces-or-tabs

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '', $k)` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been answered many times on Stackoverflow, perhaps you should have researched first, but this should solve the problem:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $k);
```

already answered

[How to strip all spaces out of a string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109325/how-to-strip-all-spaces-out-of-a-string-in-php)

[Remove excess whitespace from within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703320/remove-excess-whitespace-from-within-a-string)

and maybe many more places...

Comment: Edited the text so it comes across as more formal and less patronizing

Comment: `preg_split` would be more elegant.

Comment: thanks, its 2.30 AM here lol

Comment: No need to use regex where PHP has simple functions to do the job - see here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/113243

Answer (score 0):

Why not use str_replace to remove all white spaces?

```
$k = "2013-01-01 12:00:00 2013-01-02 12:00:00 2013-01-03 12:00:00";
$k = str_replace(" ","",$k); // Replace white space, with no space in $k
echo $k; // 2013-01-0112:00:002013-01-0212:00:002013-01-0312:00:00
```

Comment: that won't remove whitespace inside the string, only from the left and right ends.

Comment: @scrowler Nice spot, updated it