# PHP show query different of sql execute

Tags: php, mysql

config.php

```
@$mysqli= mysqli_connect($servername, $username_bd, $password_bd, $dbname);
if($mysqli->connect_error)
    return false;
```

insert.php

```
include 'config.php';        
$DateDefault = '2015-07-30 00:00:00
2015-08-30 00:00:00';

 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (date) VALUES ('$DateDefault')";        
   if($query = $mysqli->query($sql)===true)
       echo "Date add successfully";
   else
       echo "Error into date";
```

show.php

```
include 'config.php';

$sql = "SELECT date FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (@$query->num_rows > 0){
    while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
        echo substr($dados['date'], 21, 19);
    }
}
```

Result:
"2015-08-30 00:00:00"

Now, when I changed the date in the phpmyadmin, for

```
"2015-07-30 00:00:00
2015-09-30 00:00:00"
```

Shows this:

```
"015-09-30 00:00:00 "
```

In localhost, using wampserver, this bug don't happen

Comment: The `date` column is two dates?

Comment: Thx for your response, the date column is 'utf8_unicode_ci'

Comment: Not charset. Actually data in the column is two dates? Column must not be a datetime field, maybe `varchar` or `text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely to do with [how different operating systems treat line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). In a nutshell, on Windows, line endings take up two characters (carriage return and newline, `\r\n`), and on most other operating systems, they occupy only one (newline, `\n`). By using specific character offsets, you're introducing the possibility of the off-by-one error you're seeing.

A simple fix would be to separate your dates by using a single space (or another character) instead of a line break. If you still want to use a line break, you can [split the string by whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792950/explode-string-by-one-or-more-spaces-or-tabs):

```
$dates = preg_split('/\s+/', $dados['date']); // Split dates by whitespace
echo $dates[1]; // Print the second date
```

Comment: My localhost is running in Windows and the server in Linux. Each OS work in a different way with line endings. I choose your second solution, because is more easy see the date in phpmyadmin with line endings when I need update manually.

thanks for resolve my problem @Jacob budin