# Count Each Words Based on Whitespace PHP

Tags: php

I have a paragraph. The paragraph contains normal words and also contains some link. This is for example :

```
@zzz http://pbs.xx.com/xxx/x/xx_xx.jpg  RT @yyyy_y: Foto Bareng zx, vc: Politik Boleh Beda Tapi Silaturahim Jalan Terus https://er.dfo/gffggf
```

What i need is to count each words based on white space. So if there is a link, that link will be count as 1 word.

So the result will be like this :
@zzz = 1, http://pbs.xx.com/xxx/x/xx_xx.jpg = 1, RT = 1 @yyyy_y: = 1, foto = 1, bareng = 1

And so on..

Is it possible ? How ?

Comment: What about `$words = explode(" ", $string)` ?

Comment: Perhaps this previous post can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792950/explode-string-by-one-or-more-spaces-or-tabs

Comment: Sorry.. please read the updated questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Helpful to you,

> **TRY THIS UPDATED CODE**

```
<?php
   $str = "@zzz http://pbs.xx.com/xxx/x/xx_xx.jpg  RT @yyyy_y: Foto Bareng zx, vc: Politik Boleh Beda Tapi Silaturahim Jalan Terus https://er.dfo/gffggf";

   $result = array_count_values(explode(' ', $str));
   arsort($result);// not neccesary
   echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [Tapi] => 1
    [Beda] => 1
    [Boleh] => 1
    [Silaturahim] => 1
    [Jalan] => 1
    [https://er.dfo/gffggf] => 1
    [Terus] => 1
    [Politik] => 1
    [vc:] => 1
    [RT] => 1
    [] => 1
    [http://pbs.xx.com/xxx/x/xx_xx.jpg] => 1
    [@yyyy_y:] => 1
    [Foto] => 1
    [zx,] => 1
    [Bareng] => 1
    [@zzz] => 1
)
```

Comment: I have tried that code. But still, i want that link is count as 1 word

Comment: @Leonard Febrianto, Please try this updated code.

Comment: @LeonardFebrianto, the solution is work for you ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I've get this result : 
[https://tco/0SE4HUUSkv
@DianSamat http://pbstwimgcom/profile_images/713079390247264256/wyT4Wf7Q_normaljpg @kompascom] => 1
    [Sekolah] => 1

Answer (score 0):

first clean extra space at the beginning and at the end with TRIM()

```
$str = trim("@zzz http://pbs.xx.com/xxx/x/xx_xx.jpg  RT @yyyy_y: Foto Bareng zx, vc: Politik Boleh Beda Tapi Silaturahim Jalan Terus https://er.dfo/gffggf");
```

and thes try this:

```
echo count(array_filter(explode(' ', $str)));
```

These do not count if there is more than one space between words
example:

```
'    word1 word2        word3    '  -> return 3
```

UPDATED
To count how many times each word appears:

```
$str = trim("@zzz http://pbs.xx.com/xxx/x/xx_xx.jpg  RT @zzz Foto Bareng zx, vc: Politik Boleh Beda Tapi Silaturahim Jalan Terus https://er.dfo/gffggf");
$data = array_filter(explode(' ', $str));
$hash = Array();
foreach($data as $word){
    if(!key_exists($word, $hash))
        $hash[$word] = 0;
    $hash[$word]++;
}
print_r($hash);
```